# Does LVM enable me to resize my /home partition?

Tags: installation, partitioning, home-directory, lvm

With 13.04 here, I'm planning on wiping my computer and reinstalling. I have two hard drives, and I've heard that LVM allows the two drives to work together, as if they are a single drive.

I've also heard that it's useful to have a separate /home partition, so it's easier to reinstall and not have to worry about your files being overwritten; however, apparently you can't resize the /home partition, which could potentially be annoying.

I believe LVM makes partition management easier, so if I use LVM and have /home on a separate partition in the LVM setup, will I be able to resize my /home partition post-installation?

(Also, feel free to correct me if any of my above assumptions about LVM or anything are unclear/incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LVM itself doesn't enable resizing `/home`, you can do this even if you don't use LVM. LVM does make it considerably easier to resize the partition, as you can do this with a simple `lvresize` command (followed by resizing the filesystem if you're enlarging, preceded by resizing the filesystem if you're shrinking). Resizing PC partitions is fiddly and error-prone.

LVM also lets you transparently spread a filesystem over two drives, if you wish. However I do not recommend this: if either of the drives fails, you would lose the whole partition.

LVM decouples hardware devices (i.e. disks) from filesystems. With LVM, you have one or more physical volumes (typically hard disks, or PC/EFI partitions on hard disks). You can assemble one or more physical volume into a volume group. You can create one or more logical volumes in a volume group, and each logical volume contains a filesystem (or something else such as swap). Logical volumes don't have to be a consecutive chunk of disk, they can even be spread over multiple physical volumes that belong to the same volume group. All these arrangements are dynamic: you can move logical volumes around and resize them, you can add or remove physical devices from volume groups, etc.